# first setw with double is left aligned, subsequent are right aligned

Tags: c++, stream, double

I was trying to affirm my knowledge about how streams work with doubles and various manipulators, and stumbled upon G++ doing something strange:

```
int main() {
    double v = 10.0/3.;
    //std::cout << v << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setprecision(2) << v << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << v << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
3.3      //why is this left aligned?
 3.33    //why is this right aligned? which is right?
```

[See it live here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14a51876a30094b7)

Then I uncommented that first cout and got different results!

```
3.33333 //which alignment is this?
  3.3   //now this is right aligned?!
 3.33   //that implies right-aligned is correct
```

Subsequent tests show that the first double I stream out is left aligned, and all subsequent doubles are right aligned:

```
double v = 10.0/3.;
std::cout << std::setw(10) << v << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << v << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setprecision(2) << v << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setprecision(2) << v << '\n';
```

Output:

```
3.33333           //well, this is left aligned
 3.33
  3.3           
  3.3             //all subsequent tests are right aligned
```

Clang++ on Coliru is doing the same thing, I presume because they're using the same library.

I know the answer to "is this a G++ bug" is no 99.9% of the time, so can someone potentially explain the behavior I'm seeing?

Comment: For what it's worth, I am not seeing the alignment behavior that you are seeing. I am using g++ 4.7.3. I assume you understand why you get different numbers of digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @RSahu: Yeah, I understand the different digit lengths, it's just the alignment that's baffling me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running this on other IDEs I would conclude that this is a problem not with g++/clang++, nor is any standard behavior, but a problem with the Coliru editor itself. I ran this on several different sites including [Rextester](http://rextester.com/ZMV85377) and [Ideone](http://ideone.com/gijfPj) and I got the correct output for all of them. This seems to be a problem only belonging to the Coliru editor.

Streams are, by default, right-justified. When setting the width using `std::setw()`, the stream will insert padding characters as specified by `out.fill()` into the beginning (or end) of the output stream. I've noticed that Coliru doesn't add any padding characters on the *first* output operation when the stream is using the default fill character (a simple space). But when I change the fill character to anything other than a space, [it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb40c5601d05bbe2) just fine.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd835f3a39162ee1 confirms that leading spaces are being consumed.  However, I question the statement "streams are by default left justified", as they appear to be right-justified by default.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, streams are *right* justified by default, my bad.

Comment: More succinct Coliru bug testcase: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e63d96d6b0d419d